# SAPUI5 - responsive form - more than one column in one row

Tags: sapui5

I like to create a SAPUI5-page with a few input fields where a few of them are next to each other in a row like in the following example:

https://plnkr.co/edit/jgkos97pTJNsKj1WQQZN?p=preview

```
<Page title="test" showNavButton="true" navButtonPress="onNavButtonPressed">
    <content>
        <Panel height="100%">
            <content>
                <l:Grid>
                    <l:content>
                        <VBox>
                            <Label text="test1" />
                            <Input value="test1"></Input>
                            <layoutData>
                                <l:GridData span="L6 M6 S6" />
                            </layoutData>
                        </VBox>
                        <VBox>
                            <Label text="test2" />
                            <Input value="test2"></Input>
                            <layoutData>
                                <l:GridData span="L6 M6 S6" />
                            </layoutData>
                        </VBox>
                        <VBox>
                            <Label text="test3" />
                            <Input value="test3"></Input>
                            <layoutData>
                                <l:GridData span="L6 M6 S6" />
                            </layoutData>
                        </VBox>
                        <VBox>
                            <Label text="test4" />
                            <Input value="test4"></Input>
                            <layoutData>
                                <l:GridData span="L6 M6 S6" />
                            </layoutData>
                        </VBox>
                        <VBox>
                            <Label text="test5" />
                            <Input value="test5"></Input>
                            <layoutData>
                                <l:GridData span="L12 M12 S12" />
                            </layoutData>
                        </VBox>
                        <VBox>
                            <Label text="test6" />
                            <Input value="test6"></Input>
                            <layoutData>
                                <l:GridData span="L12 M12 S12" />
                            </layoutData>
                        </VBox>
                    </l:content>
                </l:Grid>
            </content>
        </Panel>
    </content>
    <footer>
        <Bar>
            <contentRight>
                <Button text="weiter" type="Accept" />
            </contentRight>
        </Bar>
    </footer>
</Page>
```

[image: not responsive]

But it is not responsive, like you see here:

[image: not responsive]

If I use a form like in this example:
https://plnkr.co/edit/RRRBGYhQRVoY7ATouKmQ?p=preview

```
<Page title="test" showNavButton="true"
    navButtonPress="onNavButtonPressed">
    <content>
        <f:Form class="sapUiResponsiveMargin" editable="true">
            <f:layout>
                <f:ResponsiveGridLayout
                  labelSpanXL="3"
                    labelSpanL="3"
                    labelSpanM="3"
                    labelSpanS="12"
                    adjustLabelSpan="false"
                    emptySpanXL="4"
                    emptySpanL="4"
                    emptySpanM="4"
                    emptySpanS="0"
                    singleContainerFullSize="true" />
            </f:layout>
            <f:formContainers>
                <f:FormContainer>
                    <f:formElements>
                        <f:FormElement label="test1">
                            <f:fields>
                                <Input value="test1"></Input>
                            </f:fields>
                        </f:FormElement>
                        <f:FormElement label="test2">
                            <f:fields>
                                <Input value="test2"></Input>
                            </f:fields>
                        </f:FormElement>
                        <f:FormElement label="test3">
                            <f:fields>
                                <Input value="test3"></Input>
                            </f:fields>
                        </f:FormElement>
                        <f:FormElement label="test4">
                            <f:fields>
                                <Input value="test4"></Input>
                            </f:fields>
                        </f:FormElement>
                        <f:FormElement label="test5">
                            <f:fields>
                                <Input value="test5"></Input>
                            </f:fields>
                        </f:FormElement>
                        <f:FormElement label="test6">
                            <f:fields>
                                <Input value="test6"></Input>
                            </f:fields>
                        </f:FormElement>
                    </f:formElements>
                </f:FormContainer>
            </f:formContainers>
        </f:Form>
    </content>
    <footer>
        <Bar>
            <contentRight>
                <Button text="weiter" type="Accept" />
            </contentRight>
        </Bar>
    </footer>
</Page>
```

it is responsive:

[image]

[image]

but I have to scroll on smaller devices. How can I combine both advantages, so that I have a responsive page, which looks good on both devices and where I don´t need to scroll on smaller devices?

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem, outline this using **sap.ui.Device.system** to check the device type.
Maybe it's an alternative:

```
if(sap.ui.Device.system.tablet && !sap.ui.Device.system.desktop){
    ...tablet related commands...
}
```

https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.Device.system

Comment: You mean, I should use two different xml-views? One for a small device and one for a big device? Actually, I like two rows like in the first example, but I like that the text over the input field moves left to it, if I have a bigger screen size, like in the second example.

Answer (score 0):

Well, instead of a form layout, you could use a grid:

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.layout.Grid

So, instead of making it a form, you just add controls there, and then you will have to cleanup a little the css because it won't be formatted for forms.